# restoring deleted wallet.dat

Tags: bitcoind

I need to restore deleted wallet.dat.

Unfortunately method with searching for

```
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00"
    "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x62\x31\x05\x00"
```

Did not produced working wallet.

The amount of bitcoins is not substantial at all, but I am thinking for searching for the address itself.

I checked on working bitcoind and wallet.dat does not seems to contain the address

- not in clear text - e.g. "12c6DSiU4Rq3P4ZxziKxzrL5LmMBrzjrJX" (I am using address I know is in the wallet rather than example address)
- not in hex - "00119B098E2E980A229E139A9ED01A469E518E6F2690AFE11C"

for convestion I am using - http://lenschulwitz.com/base58

wallet.dat does not have password. Does `bdb` uses some compression?

Any idea if I can search for the address?

Comment: is 12c6DSiU4Rq3P4ZxziKxzrL5LmMBrzjrJX your wallet address??
or just a random one you used?

Comment: It's the most famous bitcoin address there is, but why do you post a question as an answer?